Set static wireless debugging port on Android 14
I have 2 Android 14 phones. Both have Wireless Debugging enabled. Both are paired with the adb server PC. All devices are connected to the same WLAN. One of the phones always uses a static port in IP Address & Port menu entry. The other does not, it always randomizes the port. Network & Debug Networking options are the same for both phones.
How to I make it keep the port static on phone (NOT with adb tcpip, it will not work in this case at all)?
Phones:

OnePlus 8 Pro (instantnoodlep, IN2020 CN), Android security update 2024-09-05 - uses dynamic port
Motorola moto g(7) plus (lake), Android security update 2024-09-05 - uses static port


What device models are you talking about (manufacturer and model name)? What is their patch level (latest installed security update)?

One of the temporary workarounds could be this:
# 1. Connect to your phone with the current dynamic port over WLAN

sudo adb connect $ANDROID_DEVICE_WLAN_IP:$PORT

# 2. Set a static port for the device. Be quick before it changes!

sudo adb -s $ANDROID_DEVICE_WLAN_IP:$PORT tcpip $PORT

# 3. Now reinitialize the connection. You will be able to use this static IP until phone reboot.

sudo adb disconnect $ANDROID_DEVICE_WLAN_IP:$PORT
sudo adb connect $ANDROID_DEVICE_WLAN_IP:$PORT

# 4. Now run anything you need to run on your phone. E.g. list all of the packages installed for a user

sudo adb -s $ANDROID_DEVICE_WLAN_IP:$PORT shell cmd package list packages --user 0

You'll need Android 12+ device & android-tools (or platform-tools) version >=35.0.1
